# Troubles with SQL Triggers

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I'm a bit new to triggers in SQL Server (2008 R2) and I'm running into a small issue. I have a the following table (some fields have been omitted for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task] (
    [TK_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TK_DateModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [TK_ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [TK_DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [TK_CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [TK_AssignedTo] [int] NULL)
```

I added a total of 3 triggers to the table:

Trigger 1 is on record creation (insert) and it sets the date created and the user that created the record.

Trigger 2 is on record update and it sets the date modified and the user that modified the record.

Trigger 3 is on record insert/update and is set to send an email to the user specified by the TK_AssignedTo field.

When I tried doing a record insert it sends multiple emails to the user. I end up getting a creation email and 2 update emails. I want the insert to hit trigger 1 and trigger 3 from the insert, but I think the update of the 'created' fields in trigger 1 is firing trigger 3 a second time, and because trigger 1 causes an update of fields it fires trigger 2, which does another update and fires trigger 3 again. I tried turning recursive triggers in the database off to prevent that from happening but I don't think that's having the desired effect and I tried putting a change in trigger 3 to prevent sending the emails when the 'created' and 'modified' fields are fired. Here's the frame of the code for trigger 3 at the moment.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_Task_SendEmail] ON [dbo].[Task] FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS
IF (NOT UPDATE(TK_DateCreated)) AND (NOT UPDATE(TK_CreatedBy)) AND (NOT UPDATE(TK_DateModified)) AND (NOT UPDATE(TK_ModifiedBy))
BEGIN
  -- Coding to send email to user on changed tasks
END
```

In this form the code to send the email doesn't run at all, even on insert. I think the UPDATE(field) function doesn't work as I hoped it would. Is there a way to disable updating those 4 fields from firing another update trigger or some other viable option to only get trigger 1 and 3 to fire on insert and trigger 2 and 3 to fire on update?

Comment: whenever you insert a record, basically its create a magic table and from there you can control, have you tried through the magic table

Comment: I was able to make some small changes and get it work correctly. Thanks for the tips

Comment: As per my answer below, if you're really only looking to send the notifcation email when `TK_AssignedTo` is inserted/updated, you probably just want to say `IF UPDATE(TK_AssignedTo)` rather than dealing with all of those `... NOT UPDATE ...` conditions.  But I may be making an invalid assumption there.

Answer (score 1):

Your first trigger can be removed if you create default values for your columns:

```
...
[TK_DateCreated] [datetime] DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[TK_CreatedBy] [int] DEFAULT SUSER_SID()
...
```

I mocked up two triggers (the `UPDATE` trigger and the email trigger):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgUpdatedRecord]
ON [dbo].[Task] FOR UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t
        SET t.TK_DateModified = GETDATE(),
            t.TK_ModifiedBy = SUSER_SID()
        FROM [dbo].[Task] t
        JOIN [inserted] i
            ON t.[TK_ID] = i.[TK_ID]
    END
GO
```

... and ...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_Task_SendEmail]
ON [dbo].[Task] FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(TK_AssignedTo) BEGIN
        PRINT 'Is this an email?'
    END
GO
```

This appears to do what you're expecting.